# Finding all subsets of a set of arrays (perl)

Tags: arrays, perl, powerset

I have a bunch of arrays @a1, @a2, ... @ak (I don't know how many). I would like to create an array that contains the union of the power sets of the arrays. i.e., some array is in the output if and only if the entries of that array are contained in @ai for some i. The output should have no duplicates.

The only way to I can think of to do this is to create an array containing the power set of each of the arrays and then union these. However, when unioning, I have to check for entry-wise equality.

Is there anything better?

Something like, take the union of all the arrays, take the power set, and then delete the stuff that shouldn't be in there won't work, since the union of the arrays is too big.

EDIT:
For example, suppose the input in (1,2), (2, 3, 4), then the output should be
(), (1), (2), (3), (4), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (2,4), (2,3,4). Any order would be acceptable.

Comment: I think you'd need to show the values of your arrays and be more specific about what you intend to do.  Are they deeply nested?

Comment: The values of the arrays are (small) integers.

Comment: Can you provide examples of input and desired output, linked to the description?  (I am not sure what you mean by some of the terms.)

Comment: Yes, what is power set (I know what the math term means, but that doesn't seem to be how you are using it).  Show sample data and output and whatever code you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check https://metacpan.org/pod/List::PowerSet

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::PowerSet 'powerset_lazy';

my @arr = (
        [1,2],
        [2,3,4],
);
my %hash;
for my $v (@arr) {
    my $ps = powerset_lazy(@$v);
    while (my $set = $ps->()) {
        my $str = join ",", @$set;
        next if $hash{$str}++;
        print "($str)\n";
    }
}
```

output

```
(1,2)
(2)
(1)
()
(2,3,4)
(3,4)
(2,4)
(4)
(2,3)
(3)
```

Comment: This relies on the elements of the sets returned by `powerset_lazy` being sorted. They appear to be in the same order as the original array, but the documentation doesn't say so. It won't work if there are non-adjacent duplicates in the original sets.

Comment: Let the OP do his required tests.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `subsets` from [`Algorithm::Combinatorics`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Combinatorics) to generate the power sets for each array
- Sort the members of each subset so that subsets containing the same values form the same sequence
- Form a string from each sorted subset, say by separating them with spaces. `"@subset"` will do that for you
- Use the string as a key for a hash element
- Do the same for all arrays
- Print the keys of the hash